# Laravel - How do I get the total number of comments?

Tags: laravel

I would like to get the total number of comments on a post.

Two models. **Post** and **Comments**. Comments has a p**olymorphic relationship** to Post. Comments can have other comments on **themselves**. They are comments on comments / Replies to a comment. This relationship is represented by the column **comment_parent** in the comment database table.

#### Here are my models:

**Post**

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable')->whereNull('comment_parent');
}
```

**Comments**

```php
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'comment_parent')->orderBy('id', 'desc');
}
```

#### Blade

In my blade, Count only shows the number of first level comments. All replies to comments
do not. How and where can I determine the number of all comments with replies count?

**post.blade.php**

```php
<h3>Comments ( {{ $post->comments->count() }} )</h3>

@foreach($comments as $comment)
    <div>{{ $comment->content }}</div>

    <!-- show replies -->
    <div>
        @foreach($comment->replies as $reply)
            <div class="bg-blue-100 ml-20 my-2">
        <div>{{ $reply->content }}</div>
            </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endforeach
```

**PostController**

```php
public function show(Post $post) {
    $post->load(['comments' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('comment_approved', true)->orderBy('id','desc');
    }]);        
        
    return view('page.post', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a new relation without the condition `->whereNull('comment_parent')` and `count()` on it.

```
public function allComments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

```
<h3>Comments ( {{ $post->allComments()->count() }} )</h3>
```

if you want to do it in the controller

```
public function show(Post $post) {
    $post->load(['comments' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('comment_approved', true)->orderBy('id','desc');
    }])->loadCount('allComments');        
        
    return view('page.post', ['post' => $post]);
}
```

then use it in the blade as

```
<h3>Comments ( {{ $post->all_comments_count }} )</h3>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's really what I've been doing so far. I thought I could do it in a query.

Comment: @MaikLowrey You can preload it in the controller, check the second part. If it answers your question mark it as "the answer" to finalize your post.